# ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module', browserify

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browserify, babelify

I am using [django-compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and I want to *es5/es6* features on my project. I am setting the pre-compiler option as follow:

```
NODE_MODULES = BASE_DIR / 'node_modules'

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/javascript',
     'browserify {{infile}} -t {node_modules}/babelify  -o {{outfile}} --presets {node_modules}/@babel/preset-env'.format(node_modules=NODE_MODULES)),
    ('module',
     'browserify {{infile}} -t {node_modules}/babelify -o {{outfile}} --presets {node_modules}/@babel/preset-env'.format(node_modules=NODE_MODULES)),
)
```

As you noticed *browserify* is installed globally and *babelify* and *@babel/preset-env* are installed locally inside the project.

From the docs `@babel/preset-env` now are the recommended presets to use, but I am getting the following error:

```
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

According to my understanding, when using *babel/preset-env*, you **do not** need any other preceding presets e.g. *babel-preset-es2015* and others, correct? if yes what are the possible reasons for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the command was working fine, it seems there was an syntax errors on how I specify the presets, anyway I have fixed like that:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/javascript',
     'browserify {{infile}} -o {{outfile}} -t [ {node_modules}/babelify --presets [ {node_modules}/@babel/preset-env ] ]'.format(node_modules=NODE_MODULES_LOCAL)),
    ('module',
     'browserify {{infile}} -o {{outfile}} -t [ {node_modules}/babelify --presets [ {node_modules}/@babel/preset-env ] ]'.format(node_modules=NODE_MODULES_LOCAL)),

)
```